# Cuda Runtime Error cudaErrorNoDevice: no CUDA-capable device is detected

Tags: python, django, cuda, chainer, cupy

I am using Chainer, Cupy for **CUDA 8.0** .
I am trying to train machine learning model using **python3.5** script, but I got this error:

```
cupy.cuda.runtime.CUDARuntimeError: cudaErrorNoDevice: no CUDA-capable
```

**What can I do to solve it?**

Environment Details for machine on which I tried to train my Deep learning model which gives details about nvidi-smi, echo CUDA_PATH, echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
root@awsml04:~# nvidia-smi
Thu Mar 21 10:37:19 2019
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.130                Driver Version: 384.130                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   38C    P0    24W / 300W |      0MiB / 16152MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Check CUDA PATH

```
root@awsml04:~# echo $CUDA_PATH
/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0
```

Check LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
root@awsml04:~# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda/lib64{LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64{LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/mpi/lib:/lib/:}}
```

check env | grep CUDA Path:

```
root@awsml04:~# env | grep CUDA
CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH_WITH_DEFAULT_CUDA=/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/mpi/lib:/lib/:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib/:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH_WITHOUT_CUDA=/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/mpi/lib:/lib/:
```

Check python3 path

```
root@awsml04:~# which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Check pip path

```
root@awsml04:~# which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
```

check installed python libraries with version details:

```
root@awsml04:~# pip3 freeze
absl-py==0.7.1
alabaster==0.7.12
alembic==1.0.8
appdirs==1.4.3
APScheduler==3.5.3
astor==0.7.1
astroid==2.1.0
awscli==1.16.76
Babel==2.6.0
backcall==0.1.0
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
bleach==1.5.0
blinker==1.3
bokeh==1.0.3
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.9.72
botocore==1.12.72
certifi==2018.11.29
chainer==5.3.0
chainerui==0.3.0
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cloud-init==18.5
cloudpickle==0.6.1
colorama==0.3.9
command-not-found==0.3
configobj==5.0.6
cpplint==1.3.0
cryptography==1.2.3
cycler==0.10.0
dask==1.0.0
decorator==4.3.0
defer==1.0.6
defusedxml==0.5.0
docutils==0.14
easydict==1.9
entrypoints==0.2.3
enum34==1.1.6
environment-kernels==1.1.1
fastrlock==0.4
filelock==2.0.13
Flask==1.0.2
future==0.17.1
gast==0.2.2
glog==0.3.1
graphviz==0.10.1
grpcio==1.19.0
h5py==2.7.1
hibagent==1.0.1
html5lib==0.9999999
idna==2.8
imagesize==1.1.0
ipykernel==5.1.0
ipyparallel==6.2.3
ipython==7.2.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.4.2
isort==4.3.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jedi==0.13.2
Jinja2==2.10
jmespath==0.9.3
jsonpatch==1.10
jsonpointer==1.9
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.2.4
jupyter-console==6.0.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.7
Keras-Preprocessing==1.0.9
kiwisolver==1.0.1
language-selector==0.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
lxml==3.5.0
Mako==1.0.7
Markdown==2.6.10
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
matplotlib==3.0.2
mccabe==0.6.1
mistune==0.8.4
mock==2.0.0
msgpack==0.6.1
nbconvert==5.4.0
nbformat==4.4.0
networkx==2.2
nose==1.3.7
notebook==5.7.4
numpy==1.15.1
oauthlib==1.0.3
olefile==0.44
opencv-python==3.4.1.15
packaging==18.0
pandas==0.23.4
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.3.1
pbr==5.1.3
pexpect==4.6.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==4.3.0
prettytable==0.7.2
prometheus-client==0.5.0
prompt-toolkit==2.0.7
protobuf==3.7.0
ptyprocess==0.6.0
pyasn1==0.4.5
pycups==1.9.73
pycurl==7.43.0
pydot==1.4.1
pygal==2.4.0
Pygments==2.3.1
pygobject==3.20.0
PyJWT==1.3.0
pylint==2.2.2
pyparsing==2.2.0
pyserial==3.0.1
python-apt==1.1.0b1+ubuntu0.16.4.2
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python-debian==0.1.27
python-editor==1.0.4
python-gflags==3.1.2
python-systemd==231
pytz==2017.3
PyWavelets==1.0.1
pyxdg==0.25
PyYAML==3.13
pyzmq==17.1.2
qtconsole==4.4.3
requests==2.21.0
roman==2.0.0
rsa==3.4.2
s3transfer==0.1.13
scikit-image==0.14.1
scikit-learn==0.20.2
scipy==1.2.0
screen-resolution-extra==0.0.0
seaborn==0.9.0
Send2Trash==1.5.0
six==1.12.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.1
Sphinx==1.8.3
sphinx-rtd-theme==0.1.9
sphinxcontrib-websupport==1.1.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.1
ssh-import-id==5.5
system-service==0.3
tensorboard==1.12.2
tensorflow==1.12.0
tensorflow-estimator==1.13.0
tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0
tensorflow-tensorboard==0.4.0rc3
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.1
testpath==0.4.2
toolz==0.9.0
tornado==5.1.1
tqdm==4.19.5
traitlets==4.3.2
typed-ast==1.1.1
tzlocal==1.5.1
ufw==0.35
unattended-upgrades==0.1
urllib3==1.24.1
virtualenv==15.0.1
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.13
widgetsnbextension==3.4.2
wrapt==1.10.11
xkit==0.0.0
```

chainer CUDA information:

```
root@awsml04:~#  python3 -c "import chainer; print(chainer.print_runtime_info())"
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/backends/cuda.py:98: UserWarning: cuDNN is not enabled.
Please reinstall CuPy after you install cudnn
(see https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/install.html#install-cudnn).
  'cuDNN is not enabled.\n'
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Platform: Linux-4.4.0-1077-aws-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
Chainer: 5.3.0
NumPy: 1.15.1
CuPy:
  CuPy Version          : 5.3.0
  CUDA Root             : /usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0
  CUDA Build Version    : 9000
  CUDA Driver Version   : 9000
  CUDA Runtime Version  : 9000
  cuDNN Build Version   : None
  cuDNN Version         : None
  NCCL Build Version    : 2307
  NCCL Runtime Version  : 2307
iDeep: Not Available
None

root@awsml04:~# python3 -c "import cupy; print(cupy.empty((3, 3)))"
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
```

Full error traceback:

```
stacktrace.py
Exception in main training loop: cudaErrorNoDevice: no CUDA-capable
device is detected Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.see-master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 302, in run
    entry.extension(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/root/.see-master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/reporter.py", line 98, in scope
    yield
  File "/root/.see-master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 299, in run
    update()
  File "/root/.see-master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updater.py", line 223, in update
    self.update_core()
  File "/root/.see-master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/multiprocess_parallel_updater.py", line 195, in update_core
    self.setup_workers()
  File "/root/.see-master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/multiprocess_parallel_updater.py", line 186, in setup_workers
    with cuda.Device(self._devices[0]):   File "cupy/cuda/device.pyx", line 106, in cupy.cuda.device.Device.__enter__
  File "cupy/cuda/runtime.pyx", line 164, in cupy.cuda.runtime.getDevice
  File "cupy/cuda/runtime.pyx", line 136, in
    cupy.cuda.runtime.check_status Will finalize trainer extensions and updater before reraising the exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chainer/train_svhn.py", line 258, in <module>
    trainer.run()
  File "/root/.see-master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 313, in run
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/root/.see-master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 302, in run
    entry.extension(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/root/.see-master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/reporter.py", line 98, in scope
    yield
  File "/root/.see-master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 299, in run
    update()
  File "/root/.see-master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updater.py", line 223, in update
    self.update_core()
  File "/root/.see-master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/multiprocess_parallel_updater.py", line 195, in update_core
    self.setup_workers()
  File "/root/.see-master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/multiprocess_parallel_updater.py", line 186, in setup_workers
    with cuda.Device(self._devices[0]):   File "cupy/cuda/device.pyx", line 106, in cupy.cuda.device.Device.__enter__
  File "cupy/cuda/runtime.pyx", line 164, in cupy.cuda.runtime.getDevice
  File "cupy/cuda/runtime.pyx", line 136, in cupy.cuda.runtime.check_status
    cupy.cuda.runtime.CUDARuntimeError: cudaErrorNoDevice: no CUDA-capable device is detected
```

Comment: Do you have NVIDIA GPU in your machine?

Comment: yes NVIDIA Tesla V100 because I am using aws p3 2xlarge instance .

Comment: CUDA 8.0 does not support Volta (V100). Use CUDA 9.0 or newer.

Comment: yes I am using cuda 9.0

Comment: @HarshalBhamare your first sentence contains the word "I am using" and "Cuda 8.0"

Comment: Your CUDA install is broken. Before trying to use complex software like chainer that depends on CUDA, you should verify your CUDA install. Instructions are given in the cuda linux install guide.

Comment: please provide instuctions

Comment: Provide the outouts of `$ nvidia-smi`, `$ echo CUDA_PATH`, `$ echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `which python3`, `which pip`, `$ pip freeze`, `python3 -c "import chainer; print(chainer.print_runtime_info())"`.

Comment: @YukiHashimoto please check details in question I updated it .

Comment: I'm very sorry that the command should be `$ echo $CUDA_PATH` and `$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: @HarshalBhamare OK, the next command you should check is `$ pip3 freeze`, `$ echo $CUDA_PATH`, `$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, (please replace the question's correspondings) and `$ python3 -c "import cupy; print(cupy.empty((3, 3)))"`

Comment: @YukiHashimoto please check your details right now please help

Comment: @HarshalBhamare The output of `pip3` suggests that you do not have `cupy`. Have you installed `cupy` to your `python3` environment?

Comment: Please provide output of `env | grep CUDA`.

Comment: @kmaehashi please check your output

Answer (score 3):

There is not enough information to guess the reason of the error, but I just suggest you to do *something*.

IMPORTANT: DO NOT logout, detach, or close your shell until all of the following.

```
$ export CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64
$ pip3 uninstall -y chainer cupy cupy-cuda80 cupy-cuda90 cupy-cuda92
$ pip3 install cupy-cuda90 --no-cache-dir && pip3 install chainer --no-cache-dir
$ git clone https://github.com/chainer/chainer.git && cd chainer && git checkout v5.3.0
$ python3 examples/mnist/train_mnist.py --gpu 0
```

If this works, subsequently try to run your script again.

Comment: how to install chainer because you provided testing method from source and this is working for chainer from last two commands

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the comment to use GPU. BTW, did the last two commands worked fine?

Comment: IMPORTANT: This question might be already solved, because no errors about GPU can be found in the current environment of the questioner ( https://github.com/chainer/chainer/issues/6596).

Comment: Yes you are correct because of your support and right now different error is comming. Can you please help me on that error sir.

Comment: 1. Posting another question for another trouble is preferable. 2. If you overcame the trouble which this question refers, please mark "solved" flag.

Comment: so shall put another question on error which is coming right now .

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I was getting this error with my real code (a bit complex with a bunch of imports):

```
import A
import B
import cupy as cp
import ...

def main(...):

    ...(bunch of operations)...
    an_array = cp.zeros((10, 10, 10), dtype=cp.float64)
    cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()    # <- Failed here, obtained: ..."cudaErrorNoDevice: no CUDA-capable device is detected"...
    ...
```

However when I was running a simple test.py as this, it ran as expected:

```
import cupy as cp


x_gpu = cp.zeros((10, 10, 10), dtype=cp.float64)
cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize() # <- Now OK!
```

So after a couple of tests I realized my original code could pass by putting a random useless array before my real code as so:

```
import A
import B
import cupy as cp
import ...

useless_array_hack = cp.zeros((10, 10, 10), dtype=cp.float64) # I guess this allow the code to load useful resources (like dlls) that will be use by the real code as well

def main(...):

    ...(bunch of operations)...
    an_array = cp.zeros((10, 10, 10), dtype=cp.float64)
    cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()    # Now OK!
    ...
```

This ain't a perfect solution but it does fill it's purpose .

**Env notes:**

- Windows 10
- python 3.8
- an available gpu
- cupy and cudatoolkit installed in a conda virtual environment